# Inequality between inner product of functions in dual space

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products, dual-spaces, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

I'm reading [Brezzi's paper on DG method](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268065746_A_Quick_Tutorial_on_DG_Methods_for_Elliptic_Problems) and is currently puzzled on how equations (5.7) is used to derive equation (5.8).

Further searches lead me to learning that the space defined $\mathbf{V}'$ is the dual space of $\mathbf{V}$. So let's say that we have $\mathbf{V} = (H^1_0 (\Omega))^2$, then let $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{f} \in \mathbf{V}'$. Is there any relationship between their defined inner product:

$$
\left( \mathbf{f}, \mathbf{v} \right)
$$

and the norm of $\mathbf{f}$ on $\mathbf{V}'$, i.e. $|| \mathbf{f} ||_{\mathbf{V}'}$? And what space would that inner product be on? The duality pairing of $\mathbf{V} \times \mathbf{V}'$?

I am not having much background in analysis, so any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not an inner product, it's a dual pairing. An inner product works on a single vector space and a dual pairing is between a vector space and its dual.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, $(f,v)$ is a duality pairing, where $f\in V'$ and $v\in V$. The key part to get from (5.7) to (5.8) is that the dual norm
$$\|f\|_V'=\sup_{w\in V:w\ne 0}\frac{(f,w)}{\|w\|_V},$$
and so we get

$$(f,v) = \frac{(f,v)}{\|v\|_V}\|v\|_{V}\le\left(\sup_{w\in V:w\ne 0}\frac{(f,w)}{\|w\|_V}\right)\|v\|_V=\|f\|_V'\|v\|_V.$$